# Redux-Form dispatch calls Action Creator, but the reducer never receives Action

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

In the example below, I am using `mapDispatchToProps` to bind the `onSubmit` event to the `save()` Action Creator. This works - the `save()` Action Creator logs the message to console.

The issue is that it does not subsequently dispatch the 'TEST_SAVE' action - i.e. the reducer never receives an action of type 'TEST_SAVE'.

I have a vanilla redux form working as below, but I am new to redux-form and I wonder what I might be doing wrong?

```
const reducers = {
  // ... your other reducers here ...
  form: formReducer.plugin({
    contact: (state, action) => {  
      switch(action.type) {
        case 'TEST_SAVE':
          return state;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
  })
};
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStore(reducer);


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onSubmit: (val) => dispatch(actionCreators.save(val)),
  }
}

var actionCreators = {   
  save: (value) => {
    console.log('SAVE action done!');
    return {type: 'TEST_SAVE', value};
  }, 
};

const MyContactForm = connect(
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ContactForm)


<Provider store={store}>
    <MyContactForm />
</Provider>
```

An excerpt of the ContactForm class:

```
class ContactForm extends Component {

  render() {
    const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >

    ....

    )

  }
}

ContactForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'contact' 
})(ContactForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const MyContactForm = connect(
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ContactForm)
```

The first parameter to `connect()` is `mapStateToProps`, not `mapDispatchToProps`. Should be:

```
const MyContactForm = connect(
  undefined, // <------------- mapStateToProps
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ContactForm)
```

Comment: Oh, such an obvious and simple thing in hindsight. Thank you Eric - most definitely for the answer, and the library as well!

Answer (score 1):

Never use `break` inside a reducer. Always return the state object.